# Is there an upside to completing the museum?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

Does completing the museum give you anything? Item, special power, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you believe The Competionist

There's nothing. Not even a bonus weapon or something.

The biggest thing you'll get is that the library icon on the save select screen turns gold.

Comment: I have Toad & Toadette in front of the castle after getting 100% of everything. That's something, I guess. :)